# How do I stop Windows 10 restarting applications that were closed during a forced update?

Tags: windows-10

I often run 3+ instances of Visual Studio as administrator, each loaded with separate solutions.

When Windows 10 performs a forced windows update, on first login after the update Windows automatically starts 3 empty, non admin. instances of Visual Studio (no solution loaded).

After waiting for them to load I then need to close them, open again as Administrator and finally load the solution.  Windows 10 is trying to be helpful but completely failing.

So how do I disable this automatic application restart behaviour?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried selecting the run as admin checkbox on `devenv.exe` Compatibility Properties?

Comment: Close the applications before the updates are installed, avoid the problem, by scheduling active hours, updates on Windows 10 are predictable.